# The difference between tum and tunc

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary

Although these two words are obviously closely related (I believe *tunc* = *tum* + *ce*), I would like to know whether they are usually **interchangeable** and the **meaning differences that exist between them**.

If I want to refer to a past time (*tum/tunc homines alas habebant*), which is appropriate? Can both be used to indicate sequentiality, like *deinde* or English *then*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Smith's suggests that *tunc* (formed from *tum* + -*ce*, the enclitic adding emphasis) differs from *tum* only in being slightly stronger; although, since either is often strengthened by *demum*, etc., to me it seems a pretty fine distinction.

When making a contrast (*tum* . . . *cum* . .), I think using *tunc*  for *tum* would be just clumsy; for the same reason I would use only *tunc*  in a contrast with *nunc*.

Comment: I'm now imagining the phrase *tunc . . . cunc . . .* :)

Comment: L&S has this to say: "Undue weight has been given by some critics to opposition to nunc and connection with cum; cf. Kritz ad Sall. J. 5, 1; Zumpt ad Cic. Verr. 2, 4, 64, § 142; 2, 5, 10, § 27. Both tum and tunc are freq. opposed to nunc, and connected with cum. "

Comment: @TomCotton, great answer. Do you know what "stronger" means in this case? Does *tunc* suggest that X is no longer the case?

Answer (score 0):

> Does tunc suggest that X is no longer the case?

It seems unlikely. At least, if it does, the English and American lawyers didn't know it. The first time I recall coming across the word tunc was in the legal phrase "nunc pro tunc," which is used about an order that is meant to take effect as of a past time and to remain in effect through the present time and into the indefinite future.